# Problems generating image from BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I just can't generate an image from blob field on my DB.

This is my whole code:

```
<?php require_once('db.php'); ?>
<?php
    @mysql_select_db($db_login, $login);

    $query_consulta_fotos = "select `foto01_NmArquivo`, `foto01_Descricao`, `foto01_Arquivo`, `foto01_Tipo`, `foto01_Tamanho` from equipamentos where id = 2";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_consulta_fotos);

    $data = @mysql_result($result,0,"foto01_Arquivo");
    $type = @mysql_result($result,0,"foto01_Tipo");

    Header( "Content-type: $type");    

    $size = 150;  // new image width
    $src = imagecreatefromstring($data); 
    $width = imagesx($src);
    $height = imagesy($src);
    $aspect_ratio = $height/$width;

    if ($width <= $size) {
      $new_w = $width;
      $new_h = $height;
    } else {
      $new_w = $size;
      $new_h = abs($new_w * $aspect_ratio);
    }

    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h); 
    imagecopyresized($img,$src,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,$width,$height);

    // determine image type and send it to the client    
    if ($type == "image/pjpeg") {    
      imagejpeg($img); 
    } else if ($type == "image/x-png") {
      imagepng($img);
    } else if ($type == "image/gif") {
      imagegif($img);
    }
    imagedestroy($img); 

mysql_free_result($consulta_fotos);
?>
```

If I echo $data and $type I get the whole char chain and the file's MIME respectively and everything seems fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: remove that exit below "$type = @mysql_result($result,0,"foto01_Tipo");" then try to disable all errors from being displayed by using ini_set('display_errors','Off') on top of your script and see if that works. If it does maybe there are some notices which you can't see because you set content-type header. To view these notices or warnings if they are there, you should comment out the lines wiht Header, imagejpg, imagepng and imagegif calls and run your script.

Comment: @Amit Thank you for your help but it didn't work. That exit was left there by mistake(I deleted it from the above code), I was using it while echoing my variables. I've disabled error and nothing. I tried to comment the header line and still nothing: no error or images. Any other ideas?